# Who is the manufacturer of this old sillcock?

Tags: plumbing, outdoor, spigot

I am looking for a replacement for the item pictured but everywhere I go they ask for a part or model number. When I explain it came with the house 30-50 years ago they say they can't help.

Does anyone know who made these so I can try to find one online?

The faucet handle cracked and we were unable to get the screw out which led to it looking like this, the threads are about 2" and the bonnet is around 3", otherwise the unit works fine and since replacing the pipe would require cutting through drywall I'd rather not have to do that.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a plumbing store/shop and asked the old guy?

Comment: Give us more and better photos, please. make sure they're focused. Show the whole thing.

Comment: picture added,  the handle was silver before it cracked if that helps

Comment: I tried sending the photos to every plumbing store i could find online, the ones that answered basically said without the make/model they cant help